# Approach to dealing with multiple upper bounds of differing data types in function declaration

Tags: generics, recursion, kotlin, projection

I have a tail recursive function in which it is possible to create nested lists, where the parameter being passed is a linked hashmap, initially of type:

```
val mapTest = LinkedHashMap<String, Any>()
```

The call to the recursion is thus,

```
matchTest(mapTest)
```

My tail recursion deconstructs the map and does a bunch of pattern matching. For simplicity's sake, it is:

```
tailrec fun <T> matchTest(testMap: Map<T,Any>): Boolean
    where T: String, // this is string on initial call
          T: List<String>{ // this is List<String> on subsequent calls

    val newMap = LinkedHashMap<List<String>, Any>()
    var found = false

    /*
        logic that can create nested lists
    */

    return when {
        found -> true
        else -> matchTest(newMap)
    }

}
```

The issue is that when the recursive call is made after the initial call, instead of passing a LinkedHashMap with a `String` type for the keys, it will have a `List` of type `String`.

Naively, I thought creating multiple upper bounds on my Generic type would take care of this (see above function declaration), but Idea gives the error that "String is not a subtype of List"...

I also tried using a star projection for the list argument, but Idea gives me an error that "Projections are not allowed on type arguments of functions and properties."

Am I barking up the wrong tree thinking that use of Generic data types would solve my problem of how to deal with the possibility that the key in my map can go from `String` to `List<String>?`

In Python, of course this would be simple, but alas...

Comment: In the current version of Kotlin, there is no way to specify that a type parameter (or any type in general) can be either A or B. Multiple type constraints work as "and" constraints: they specify that a type parameter must be both A and B.

Comment: Darn it! Thanks for confirming what I thought. I'll have to play around with my data structure then to come up with a more general form.